# Twitter Bootstrap an Essential Tool

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi i've started to just develop my *own site* and I ve gone through many searches and found that **twitter Bootstrap** an immediate help for the starter.Is there any sugessions about it.Is my choice a best one.

> Thanks

Comment: What sort of suggestions, exactly? I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is a User Interface framework.  This means you can use it to design the layouts for all the pages on your site.  It is good. I use it on my site.

If you are looking for a tool to help you deal with the inner workings of your site, storing data, authenticating users etc then you are looking for a web application framework - Bootstrap cannot help you with any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a very robust css framework. It makes sure that you're site will work on many different platforms. Its visually appealing. But, if you don't customize it, your site will look like everyone else's. I'd be sure to check out http://builtwithbootstrap.com/ to see what can be done with the framework.